# Optimizing MiniZinc constraints for a scheduling problem

Tags: optimization, scheduling, combinatorics, minizinc

I am trying to use MiniZinc to solve a scheduling problem. Here is the main setting:

- I have a certain number of students
- They rank 7 topics in order of preference
- They will be assigned 4 of such topics
- There is 4 time slots available in the timetable for all of these

Of course students cannot attend two topics at the same time, and there are also a minimal/maximal size for each topic (but there may be various classes of a same topic, or no class of another topic). This is the most important constraint and we could see that as a satisfiability problem, even though trying to maximize the hapinness of the students is a good bonus.

I tried the following approach, translating all my constraints:

```html
int: n; % number of students
int: m; % number of topics
int: c; % number of courses each student will take
int: maxseats; % number of seats available per course max
int: minseats; % number of seats minimum per course
int: timeslots; % possible time slots for the courses

set of int: STUDENTS=1..n; % students
set of int: PREFERENCE=1..m; % possible preference rankings
set of int: TOPICS=1..m; % different topics
set of int: TIMESLOTS=1..timeslots; 

array[STUDENTS,TOPICS] of PREFERENCE: preference; % ranking of topics by each student

array[STUDENTS,1..c] of var TOPICS: course; % topics assigned to each student
array[TOPICS] of var TIMESLOTS: schedule; % time slot assigned to topics

include "alldifferent.mzn";
constraint % students have different topics
  forall(student in STUDENTS)(alldifferent([course[student,i] | i in 1..c])); 
  
constraint % no student has two topics at the same time
  forall(student in STUDENTS)(forall(i,j in 1..c where i<j)(schedule[course[student,i]] != schedule[course[student,j]])); 
  
constraint % less students per topic than available seats (NOTE : groups can be duplicated)
  forall(topic in TOPICS)(sum(student in STUDENTS where exists(i in 1..c)(course[student,i] = topic))(1) <= maxseats); 
  
constraint % more students per topic than the minimum
  forall(topic in TOPICS)(sum(student in STUDENTS where exists(i in 1..c)(course[student,i] = topic))(1) >= minseats); 

var int: satisfaction = sum(student in STUDENTS)(sum(i in 1..c)(preference[student, course[student,i]])); 

solve minimize satisfaction;
```

The problem is that this works for few students, but it is far from working in a reasonable time for my list of students (I have about 100, which I though was not that many, but even 20 does not reach any conclusion in ten minutes).

Here is part of my data file (cutting some students for simlplicity, but it is already too long:

```html
n = 10;
m = 7;
c = 3; 
maxseats=18; 
minseats=1; 
timeslots=4; 

preference =[|
1,2,5,3,7,4,6|
6,4,7,5,1,2,3|
1,2,6,4,5,7,3|
5,3,1,2,6,4,7|
5,2,1,6,3,7,4|
7,5,1,6,3,2,4|
1,7,6,4,5,3,2|
1,4,2,6,3,5,7|
4,6,1,5,2,3,7|
1,6,4,3,5,7,2|
|];
```

Are there any relevant constraints or structure I can add to help the solvers to do the job?

*** **Edit.** Here is a further attempt. I noticed another problem: basically, groups cannot be too large (less than maxseats), thus there will be various groups of each topic (with same teacher). Hence, not only cannot students have lectures at the same time, but various groups of the same topic also ought to be distinguished, with the constraint of not having lectures at the same time. This looks like a much larger combinatorial problem! Maybe there is a clever way to package it, but for now I essentially chose to duplicate the topics.

This is the model:

```html
    int: n; % number of students
    int: m; % number of topics
    int: c; % number of courses each student will take
    int: g=5; % number of instances of each course
    int: maxseats; % number of seats available per course max
    int: minseats; % number of seats minimum per course
    int: timeslots; % possible time slots for the courses

    set of int: STUDENTS=1..n; % students
    set of int: PREFERENCE=1..m; % possible preference rankings
    set of int: TOPICS=1..g*m; % different topics
    set of int: TIMESLOTS=0..timeslots; 

    array[STUDENTS,1..m] of PREFERENCE: preference; % ranking of topics by each student
    array[STUDENTS, PREFERENCE] of TOPICS: prefRank = array2d(STUDENTS, PREFERENCE, [rank
       | student in STUDENTS, p in 1..m, rank in 1..m where preference[student, rank] == p]);

    array[STUDENTS,1..c] of var TOPICS: course; % topics assigned to each student
    array[TOPICS] of var TIMESLOTS: schedule; % time slot assigned to topics

    function int: topicToGroupFix(var int: t) =
        fix(((t-1) mod g) + 1);
    
    function var int: topicToTopic(var int: t) =
        ((t-1) div g) + 1;
    function int: topicToTopicFix(var int: t) =
        fix(((t-1) div g) + 1);

    function int: topicGroupToTopic(int: t, int: gg) =
        ((t-1) * g) + gg;
    
    array[TOPICS] of var 0..maxseats: number; % number of people taking each course
    constraint 
      forall (topic in TOPICS)(number[topic] = sum(student in STUDENTS, i in 1..c)(course[student,i] == topic)); 

    include "globals.mzn";

    constraint % before using another topic group make sure the previous one has students in it
      forall(t in 1..m, gg in 1..g-1)( number[topicGroupToTopic(t,gg+1)] > 0 -> number[topicGroupToTopic(t,gg)] >= minseats );

    constraint % if students are assigned to a topic group it must have enough
      forall(t in TOPICS)( number[t] > 0 -> number[t] >= minseats );

   constraint % make sure topics are slotted at different times
       forall(t in 1..m)( alldifferent_except_0([schedule[x] | x in topicGroupToTopic(t,1)..topicGroupToTopic(t,g)]));

    array[STUDENTS,1..c] of var PREFERENCE: courseRank;

    constraint % channeling constraint to obtain topic ranking
      forall(student in STUDENTS, i in 1..c)(courseRank[student, i] = prefRank[student, topicToTopic(course[student, i])]);

    constraint % no student has two topics at the same time
      forall(student in STUDENTS)(alldifferent([schedule[course[student,i]] | i in 1..c]));

    constraint % students have different topics (and break symmetries)
      forall(student in STUDENTS)(strictly_increasing([courseRank[student, i] | i in 1..c]));
      
    constraint % students have different topics
      forall(student in STUDENTS)(alldifferent([topicToTopic(course[student, i]) | i in 1..c])); 

    constraint % fairness - don't want any one student to get a bad schedule relative to others
      forall(student in STUDENTS)(sum([courseRank[student,i] | i in 1..c]) <= 
                                   min([sum([courseRank[s,i] | i in 1..c]) | s in STUDENTS where s != student])+1);
    %constraint % fairness - don't want any one student to get a bad schedule relative to others
    %  forall(student in STUDENTS)(sum([courseRank[student,i] | i in 1..c]) <= 
    %                               min([sum([courseRank[s,i] | i in 1..c]) | s in STUDENTS])+1);

    constraint % fairness - don't a student get a much worse choice than others
      forall(student in STUDENTS)(courseRank[student,c] <= min([courseRank[s,c] | s in STUDENTS where s != student])+1);
    %constraint % fairness - don't a student get a much worse choice than others
    %  forall(student in STUDENTS)(courseRank[student,c] <= min([courseRank[s,c] | s in STUDENTS])+1);

    % break symmetries on the schedule
    constraint forall(t in TOPICS)(if number[t] == 0 then schedule[t] == 0 else schedule[t] >= 1 /\ schedule[t] <= t endif);
    %constraint forall(t in 1..m)(schedule[t] <= t);
    constraint forall(t in 1..m*g-1)(schedule[t+1] <= (max(x in TOPICS)(schedule[x])+1));   
      
    var int: satisfaction = sum(student in STUDENTS, i in 1..c)(courseRank[student,i]);

    solve :: int_search(courseRank, smallest, indomain_min)
       minimize satisfaction;
    %solve minimize satisfaction;

    output(["satisfaction Level: \(satisfaction)\n"]);
    output(["student", "\t", "topic", "\t\t", "group", "\t\t", "courseRank", "\n"]);
    output([show(student) ++ "\t" ++ show([topicToTopicFix(course[student,i]) | i in 1..c]) ++ "\t" ++
                                     show([topicToGroupFix(course[student,i]) | i in 1..c]) ++ "\t" ++
            show([courseRank[student,i] | i in 1..c]) ++ "\n" | student in STUDENTS]);

    output(["studentsPerTopic: \(number)\n"]);
    output(["schedule: \([schedule[x] | x in TOPICS])\n"]);
```

The same data file can be used, but with 100 students, even c=1 (i.e. only one lecture to assign, which should be essentially trivial!) does not finish in hours and hours...

Is there anything I can do or is the problem really combinatorically too big for MiniZinc?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to tweak your model:

```
include "globals.mzn";
int: n; % number of students
int: m; % number of topics
int: c; % number of courses each student will take
int: maxseats; % number of seats available per course max
int: minseats; % number of seats minimum per course
int: timeslots; % possible time slots for the courses

set of int: STUDENTS=1..n; % students
set of int: PREFERENCE=1..m; % possible preference rankings
set of int: TOPICS=1..m; % different topics
set of int: TIMESLOTS=1..timeslots; 
set of int: COURSES=1..c;

array[STUDENTS,TOPICS] of PREFERENCE: preference; % ranking of topics by each student

array[STUDENTS,COURSES] of var TOPICS: course; % topics assigned to each student
array[TOPICS] of var TIMESLOTS: schedule; % time slot assigned to topics

constraint % students have different topics; we thus enforce topics per student to be sorted
  forall(student in STUDENTS, i in 1..c-1)(course[student,i] < course[student,i+1]); 
  
constraint % no student has two topics at the same time
  forall(student in STUDENTS)(alldifferent([schedule[course[student,i]] | i in COURSES])); 
  
constraint % students per topic within allowed bounds (NOTE : groups can be duplicated)
  forall(topic in TOPICS)(sum([(course[student,i] == topic)| student in STUDENTS, i in COURSES]) in minseats .. maxseats); 
  
var n..n*m: dissatisfaction = sum(student in STUDENTS)(sum(i in COURSES)(preference[student, course[student,i]])); 

constraint dissatisfaction < n * 5;
```

Sadly, for the given dataset, the solution time is still beyond my patience.

---

**Update:**

My second attempt with Boolean decision variables which represent the presence or absence of students per topic.

```
include "globals.mzn";
int: n; % number of students
int: m; % number of topics
int: c; % number of courses each student will take
int: maxseats; % number of seats available per course max
int: minseats; % number of seats minimum per course
int: timeslots; % possible time slots for the courses

set of int: STUDENTS=1..n; % students
set of int: PREFERENCE=1..m; % possible preference rankings
set of int: TOPICS=1..m; % different topics
set of int: TIMESLOTS=1..timeslots; 
set of int: COURSES=1..c;

array[STUDENTS,TOPICS] of PREFERENCE: preference; % ranking of topics by each student

array[TOPICS, STUDENTS] of var bool: course; % students assigned to topics
array[TOPICS] of var TIMESLOTS: schedule; % time slot assigned to topics
 
constraint % enforce the number of courses per student
  forall(student in STUDENTS)(c = sum([course[t, student] | t in TOPICS]));
  
constraint % no student has two topics at the same time
  forall(student in STUDENTS)(alldifferent([schedule[t] | t in TOPICS where course[t, student]])); 
  
constraint % students per topic within allowed bounds (NOTE : groups can be duplicated)
  forall(topic in TOPICS)(sum([course[topic, student] | student in STUDENTS]) in minseats .. maxseats); 
  
constraint %  limit the dissatisfaction of students
  max([preference[student, t] | student in STUDENTS, t in TOPICS where course[t, student]]) < 4;
```

Using solver backends Chuffed, Google OR Tools or COIN-BC, this is solved in under 10 seconds.
No solution is found, if the upper limit of worst preference value is lower than 3. This is no surprise with two topics to be chosen.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying, it seems that the value of $c$ (the number of topic to be picked by each student) is really making the time blow up. For 1 and 2 it is fine, however for 3 it is already far too much (and in fact I would need 5). And it is only for 10 students, I have a bit more. Maybe there is another way of modelizing the problem that would make the structure/constraints stronger

Comment: Thanks for the new version! However isn't it worse to use boolean matrices, since the number of variables is higher? It is good if it works quicker though. I need n=140 and c=5 in fact. I have a new model (with new symmetry breaking constraints, like increasing order for the schedule, and still same variables) working well for n=140 and c=3 (maybe not so well, still 10 minutes with coin-bc), but it is far too slow for c=4. I will soon post a new version of my trials here, once it is more satisfactory! But we may be far from c=4 or 5 being doable (even just with satisfy rather than minimize)

Comment: In terms of bits, the Boolean array is not worse than an array of multi-bit variables. The constraints become easier. It might be worthwhile to use MiniZinc [search annotations](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.5.5/en/mzn_search.html).

Comment: Another idea is to assign the students to topics first and then schedule the topics in a second phase.

Comment: Well noted for the annotations, thanks!

Comment: Assigning the topics first could leave us with an unsatisfiable situation at the end? (e.g. all the couple of topics appearing among the students, while at least two lectures should overlap)

Comment: I tried to assign the topics in a second phase, with 4 topics. It does not give me any result after many hours of computations, sadly (maybe should I talk about this issue in a separate question?). In between, I gave some extra trials and implemented the problem with possible multiple instances of each topic (which are necessary), I edited my OP to add this version... which does run but is far too long to finish (even with a single course to assign, i.e. c=1)